# returning a key from inner hashmap that has lowest value

Tags: java

I have a nested HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, Map<String,Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

The key for the nested map may have multiple values:

```
{Color={Red=4, Blue=6}}
```

I want to be able to return the key of the nested map that has the lowest value. In this case, if I gave the key `Color` from the outer map, I want to have `Red` returned.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: show what have you tried so far?

Comment: The fact that the map is the value of another map is irrelevant to the solution. Just retrieve the map and find the max entry.

Answer (score 2):

1. Get the inner map by key.
2. Get the `Iterator` of the inner map.
3. Assign the first kvp as the minimum.
4. Loop through the iterator checking if any subsequent kvp is less than the minimum and assign it if true.
5. Return the minimum's key.

Code Sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Map<String,Integer>> map = new HashMap() {{
        put("Color", new HashMap() {{
            put("Red", 4);
            put("Orange", 1);
            put("Blue", 6);
            put("Yellow", 2);
        }});
    }};

    System.out.println(getInnerKeyWithLowestValue(map, "Color"));
}

public static String getInnerKeyWithLowestValue(Map<String, Map<String,Integer>> map, String outerKey) {
    Map<String, Integer> innerMap = map.get(outerKey);

    // Make sure inner map was retrieved
    if (innerMap != null) {
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> it = innerMap.entrySet().iterator();

        Map.Entry<String, Integer> minimum = it.next();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, Integer> next = it.next();
            if (next.getValue() < minimum.getValue()) {
                minimum = next;
            }
        }

        return minimum.getKey();
    }
    return ""; // Inner map doesn't exist
}
```

Results:

```
Orange
```

Answer (score 1):

If Java 8 is a option for you, it is easy to write a very concise method to do that:

```
public static String lowestValueKey(Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> map, String key) {
    return map.get(key).entrySet().stream()
            .min(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
            .get().getKey();
}
```

Also using Maps inside Maps can be very tedious sometimes. You may consider using `Table<String, String, Integer>` from [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table) library.

Answer (score 0):

Get the Hashmap from the inner hashmap and sort the hashmap based on the value which is shown in the link [enter link description here](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/03/java-sort-map-by-value/). Obviously firs entry will be the lowest value in your innerhashmap.

Comment: Only the third approach under that link passes a basic sanity check. ValueComparator breaks the fundamental API contract of Comparator

Comment: Getting the max value is an O (n) problem, but your advice to first do a full sort turns it into O (n2) worst case.